# getting variable set inside executed script through python system/subprocess cmd

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to get a variable's value set inside shell script executed using python system(). HOwever I dont have idea how to fetch that value after os.system() call is executed. whether it can be fetched using the python subprocess command.

```
cmd = "script.sh --input1 "+ inputValue1 + " --input2 '"+ inputValue2 + "' --output-file " + pathToOutputFile
os.system(cmd)
```

The script.sh during execution sets one local variable when executing some function. I want to fetch that variable's value post os.system() is executed. Whether passing another argument to script and getting that value set inside script and use that value when system() is completed - is it possible using os.system() or subprocess() in python?

please help with any code snippet that can get the variable value in python.

thanks for your pointers.

Comment: Have you tried with env variables? They should be accessible from anywhere?

Comment: no, as the value I am expecting one credential, I am bit hesitant to put in an env variable and access it.